# For loop running only once in python

Tags: python, pymongo

Here is my code below:

```
import pymongo
import sys

client=pymongo.MongoClient('localhost',27017)
db=client.test 

try:              
     cursor= db.alb.find()         
     cursor1=db.img.find()             
     cntr=db.alb.count()        
     print "looping starts..."     
     for im in cursor1:                                                                                                        
         id1=im['_id']
         cnt=0
         print id1         
         for image in cursor:
             ig=image['images']
             print "image value:" , ig
             print "id value:" , id1
             if (id1 == ig):
                break;
             else:
                cnt=cnt+1
                print "count value", cnt
                if (cnt == cntr):
                   print "removing..."
                   db.img.remove({'_id':id1})
                   print id1
                   print cnt

except Exception as e:
     print "unexpected error", type(e),e
```

I have following data in alb collection :

```
id:0 images:366
id:1 images:367
id:2 images:368
id:3 images:369
id:4 images:370
id:5 images:380
id:6 images:371
id:7 images:372
```

I have below in img collection:

```
id:365
id:345
id:372
id:370
id:371
id:380
id:381
```

basically from the above code `id:365` , `id:345`, `id:381` should be removed from the img collection, but my code removes only `id:365` in the img collection.

Please help me in correcting the errors in this code.....

Comment: what is length of `cursor1` ? `len(cursor1)` and write debug statements like `print "Debug 1 id1 ", id1`

Comment: try `db=client["test"]`

Comment: I tried with len(cursor1) i get error like object of type cursor has no length(). Also how can we find the length of cursor...it stores all the documents right....?

Comment: Kalai : In my earlier code i have tried with client.test...I have got output for that...i think its irrelavant to the problem which i have got now...both are going to do the same job anyway...

Comment: CAn you put in question, what you are trying to do with your code?what is the basis for removing `id:365 , id:345, id:381` ?

Comment: I have two collections basically alb and img and are connected to each with the images in alb collection present as id in image collection so i want to remove all the id in the images collection that which are not present in the alb collection as image value. you can see the two collection sample values which i have provided, by which you will understand why do i want to remove the above specified id in the image collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work .This is due to the fact that a `generator` is provided when you call `db.alb.find()` **the generator value is exhausted when you iterate over it** in the for loop so second time when you iterate it there is no value in it so only for loop runs only once

```
import pymongo
import sys

client=pymongo.MongoClient('localhost',27017)
db=client.test 

try:              

    cursor1=db.img.find()             
    cntr=db.alb.count()        
    print "looping starts..."     
    for im in cursor1:                                                                                                        
        id1=im['_id']
        cnt=0
        print id1 
        cursor= db.alb.find()   #move it here      
        for image in cursor:
            ig=image['images']
            print "image value:" , ig
            print "id value:" , id1
            if (id1 == ig):
                break;
            else:
                cnt=cnt+1
                print "count value", cnt
                if (cnt == cntr):
                print "removing..."
                db.img.remove({'_id':id1})
                print id1
                print cnt

except Exception as e:
    print "unexpected error", type(e),e
```

Comment: Thanks a lot....I have been struggling of why the logic is not working....Now its good...working perfectly.... :) :) thanks again....:)

Comment: I used this code as my base code with examing of collections have few documents. now i have 1 lakh docs in the images collection and tried and i get the below error : string indices must be integers. I have posted my code in the answers section please look into that...

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways of doing it. For example, what about something like this:

```
# Get all image identifiers
alb_images = [image['images'] for image in cursor]

# Find the ones to remove
images_to_remove = [im for im in cursor1 if im['_id'] not in alb_images]
```

After the above, the `images_to_remove` should contain the images to remove from your `img` collection.

<sub>[Note: This is probably not the most effective nor the most Pythonic way of doing it.]</sub>

Comment: I think instead of alb_images we can use cursor.values()

Comment: actually i am new to python and sorry i dont understand the line of code which you have used....but from seeing i feel like it is same as what i have written...if not please correct me if i understood it wrong.

Comment: @Svati You might want to read about [list comprehension](http://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
import pymongo
import sys

client=pymongo.MongoClient('localhost',27017)
db=client.rop 

try:

   cntcur=db.albums.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$images"},{"$group":{"_id":"null","count":{'$sum':1}}}])
   cursor1=db.images.find()    

   for im in cursor1:         
       id1=int(im['_id'])
       cnt=0         
       cursor= db.albums.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$images"}])
       print id1         
       for image in cursor:
           print "moving to images collection"             
           ig=image['images']
           if (id1 == ig):
              break;
           else:
              cnt=cnt+1              
              if (cnt == cntr):
                 print "removing"  
                 db.images.remove({'_id':id1})                

 except Exception as e:
     print "unexpected error", type(e),e
```

for the above code i get string indices must be integer.I get in line  ig=image['images']

Comment: could you provide full trace back and ask it as a another question and remove this one it is against SO policy :)

Comment: what is data type of `image` ? print "Debug Data type of image:",  type(image)

Comment: I have posted it as another question "String indices must be integers in one place of code in python"

Answer (score 0):

I do not know where is your code fails. Write **debug statement** at right position so you can get where code fails.

e.g.

```
>>> for i in range(1,5):
...     print "Debug 1- i: ", i
...     for j in range(10,15):
...         print "Debug 1.1- j ", j
...         if j==13:
...             break
```

1. In code print length of `cursor1` (I think by count method)
2. print `cursor1` value after remove statement i.e `db.img.remove({'_id':id1})`

One more **can you remove collections from the img after all process** `db.img.remove({'_id':id1})`

create list which save `id1` values and after process just you remove all id's of list from the `db.img`

```
remove_ids = []

# remove statement, append id value to list
remove_ids.append(id1)

# After process do 
for id in remove_ids:
    db.img.remove({'_id':id})
```

Comment: I have used print after the for loops to find whether it is looping through each docs

Comment: add print output in the question. One more can you remove collections from the img after all process `db.img.remove({'_id':id1})`